# Error in get() in R

Tags: r, get

I have several vectors:

```
aa<-c("a","b","b","b",NA)
bb<-c("g","g","g","i",NA)
cc<-c("y","y","x","y",NA)

all<-c("aa","bb","cc")
```

I wrote a loop so that all NA will be replaced by the most frequent levels:

```
for (i in 1:3)
{

    get(all[i])[is.na(get(all[i]))]<-names(which.max(table(get(all[i]))))
}
```

But it doesn't work?  Can someone explain why?  I suspect it's something to do with the get() function?
Thank you

Comment: "But it doesn't work" <- Please take the time to explain how it didn't work and if there is an error message include that in your question verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 lst1 <- lapply(mget(all),function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <-names(which.max(table(x)))
                               x})
 lst1
 # $aa
 #[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "b"

 # $bb
 #[1] "g" "g" "g" "i" "g"

 #$cc
 #[1] "y" "y" "x" "y" "y"
```

In case, you wanted to replace the `NA` in original variable

```
 list2env(lst1, envir=.GlobalEnv)
 aa
 #[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "b"
```

Comment: Like the `for` loop going :-)